# git - Jenkins build failed

Tags: git, jenkins

Morning,

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress xx@git.xx.xxx.com:xx-smoke-tests +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1723)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1459)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:506)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:152)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to rango slave 1(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:252)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor577.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1046)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ERROR: null
```

At first glance this appears to result froma failure to clone the origin from GIT. Any advice?

Comment: That's exactly what it is.  Verify that the git repo is behaving (ssh into the box if need be).  If you don't care about spinning some cycles, you could also blow away the workspace and retry (in case somehow the local repo wedged).

Comment: Thanks for the quick validation.. However onto the jenkins server. I ran the git line that seems to fail and get this:

git fetch --tags --progress xxid@git.xx.xx.com:xx-smoke-tests +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Warning: Permanently added 'git.xx.xx.com,x.x.x.x' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From git.xx.xx.com:xx-smoke-tests
   eb61f0f..4bd5b8f  master     -> origin/master
[build@gserver]$ ls -lrt
total 0

Comment: I suppose you could toss a "-a" in your ls to make sure that a git repo was actually pulled and/or run some other git command to make sure it's reasonably sane (like a plain "git branch" to make sure something shows up).  Might it be a bad check-in into your branch?

Comment: Hm magically started working... I will monitor the next few runs and equate what the differences are. Thank for you help

Comment: Good luck!  Might be worth a quick check via dmesg on the Jenkins server (if running Linux) to make sure you're not getting filesystem corruption errors just in case.